# Everything I open, crashes

Tags: windows-7, drivers, crash

My sister has been complaining about a problem with her notebook for a year or so: All the programs that are opened on the notebook crash after a while. It may take a while but it always closes.
Chrome, Firefox, Spotify, Microsoft Office programs, and even Windows Explorer crashs and provide no error message. Many times in Firefox, before crashing, a message appears saying that the page has crashed.

This began last year,when she had sent her notebook to format in an acquaintance's shop our here from the neighborhood. We do not have the money to pay an inspection of a technician in the Notebook so i'm looking for a solution. Another detail is that the internet also drops from time to time,a red X appears on top of the the internet icon.

I did a search to find something that could solve the problem but I did not find anything that resembles this. So I ended up looking for some Windows error log program and found the "Event Viewer". Within it in the Windows Logs tab, in Application, Security and System there are many errors: In Applications, referring to the "Office Software Protection Platform Service"; In security, there are a lot of Audit failures; In System, there is a lot of them: MsMpEng errors, APPCRASH, Service and Network errors as well.

I'm not sure what to do with it, I've already scanned it with an antivirus and nothing, the only option I have left is to Format, but I really wanted to try to solve it without needing to get to that point.
Thank you very much.

tl; dr: Programs crashing without message after formatting. Event Viewer points to a lot of errors.

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: I suggest reformat... But I'd guess you don't have Correct drivers

Comment: I would suggest the following:
1. Create the directory C:\dumps
2, Download ProcDump from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump to that location.
3. In an admin prompt CD to that directory, e.g. CD \dumps
4. Run:
procdump -ma -i C:\dumps

Next time a process crashes it will write a dump that directory.  Can you provide a link to one or two of these dump files from different processes?
Note: You can remove the procdump registry entries running procdump -u

Answer (score 0):

could be missing files, hdd, thermal, ram, wrong clocking, bad wiring...

1. listen for unusual or missing noises like fans or hdd

unlikely but easy:

check if your hdd (partition c) have enough space left (min. 2-4GB)

if you know how the bios works, try to reset to default,that should restore a default clocking, 
otherwise don't care about that, 
but before the reset take some pictures of the settings.

if it's not that easy, i would advise you to format your hdd-partition "C" and reinstall your os, cause most issues are shown or fixed then.

first check everthing got a backup. think about all the hardware-drivers, favorites, e-mails and the docs, vids and pics.

you could do a lot of tests instead, but mostly you can't fix them without reinstalling your os.

if you are able to, change the hdd or ram (i read about bad ram but i've never
seen it over 20 years).

the bigger problems are cooling or other internal hardware issues, then you have to open the notebook.

Comment: Please use the EDIT button and add formatting and punctuation to make your answer more clear.

Comment: it was my ram. I disassemble the notebook and checked the RAM. It was a double channel between a 2 GB and a 4 GB from two differents brands, with the same frequency. I took the one with least memory first and tested: the problem continued. But when i tested with only the 2 GB, it worked. Apparently, the one with 4 GB is scratchy, so is not working properly.  Thanks for the help!